# How to fix the X-axis number orders in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot density function with ggplot2. While the graph didn't show up as expected, in which the X-axis numbers didn't show in order. Could you help solve this problem please? thanks!

I am running R studio with ggplot2.

```
data<- rbind(data1, data2, data3)

data4<-data.frame(data$type, data$ret)

a<-ggplot(data4, aes(x=data.ret))
```

`#data.ret` is the data I want to have densities

`#data.type` is the data that groups the data.ret

```
a+ geom_density(aes(group=data.type, fill=data.type))

a+ geom_density(aes(group=data.type))
```

I expected the X-axis to run from negative to positive, from small to big, while it didn't run in that rank.

Comment: Hi there and welcome! Could you provide a reproducible example? We don't have data1, data2 or data 3. Also, have a look at the suggestions around the edit box to see how you can format your post (for example ``` goes around code). I would guess that the variable on your x-axis (data.ret?) is not formatted as numeric or as a factor but its hard to tell without a reproducible example. It looks as if R doesn't understand that there is an order in data.ret.

Comment: if a reproducible example is not doable, you could give us the part of the output of ```str(data4)``` that tells us what format data.ret has?

Comment: After checking with 'str(data)' and changing the format of the data, I got the right results. Thanks and I truly appreciate your help!